# Override legend color in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

To explain what I want here's the example I've been trying to get to work:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:10, y=1:10,linetype = "Group A (CO[2] )"),color="red", size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:10, y=2:11,linetype = "Group B (SO[2] )"), size=3, color="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:10, y=3:12,linetype = "Group C (NO[2] )"),color="red", size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(x=1:10, y=4:13,linetype = "Group D (XO[2] )"), size=3, color="blue") +
  scale_color_manual("Legend Title",
                     values=c("Group A (CO[2] )"="red", "Group B (SO[2] )"="blue","Group C (NO[2] )" = "red","Group D (XO[2] )" = "blue"),
                     labels=c(expression("(N"[R]*",N"[B]*")"),
                              expression("(N"[R]*",I"[B]*")"),
                              expression("(I"[R]*",N"[B]*")"),
                              expression("(I"[R]*",I"[B]*")")))+
  scale_linetype_manual("Legend Title", 
                        values=c("Group A (CO[2] )"="dashed", "Group B (SO[2] )"="dotted","Group C (NO[2] )" = "twodash","Group D (XO[2] )" = "dotdash"),
                        labels=c(expression("(N"[R]*",N"[B]*")"),
                                 expression("(N"[R]*",I"[B]*")"),
                                 expression("(I"[R]*",N"[B]*")"),
                                 expression("(I"[R]*",I"[B]*")")))+
  guides(color = "none")
```

Which produces the graph attached, in which the legend color is all blue, but since I don't care about the color in the legend, I want the legend to be black, and the lines to remain with the same color and shape. I thought the guides(color = "none") would do it but it doesn't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fssoG.png)

With the code I provided I want the color in the legend to be black, but it's blue instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` to set the `color` to `"black"` for the `linetype` legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, linetype = "Group A (CO[2] )"), color = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(x = 1:10, y = 2:11, linetype = "Group B (SO[2] )"), size = 3, color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x = 1:10, y = 3:12, linetype = "Group C (NO[2] )"), color = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(x = 1:10, y = 4:13, linetype = "Group D (XO[2] )"), size = 3, color = "blue") +
  scale_linetype_manual("Legend Title",
    values = c("Group A (CO[2] )" = "dashed", "Group B (SO[2] )" = "dotted", "Group C (NO[2] )" = "twodash", "Group D (XO[2] )" = "dotdash"),
    labels = c(
      expression("(N"[R] * ",N"[B] * ")"),
      expression("(N"[R] * ",I"[B] * ")"),
      expression("(I"[R] * ",N"[B] * ")"),
      expression("(I"[R] * ",I"[B] * ")")
    )
  ) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = "black")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that does what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan's answer is obviously the easiest solution, but if your plot is more complicated than the example in your question, another potential alternative is to create a 'long' dataframe and specify 'color' outside of `aes()`, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y1 = 1:10,
                 y2 = 2:11, y3 = 3:12,
                 y4 = 4:13)
long_df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-x,
               names_to = "group") %>%
  mutate(lty = case_when(group == "y1" ~ "Group A (CO[2] )",
                         group == "y2" ~ "Group B (SO[2] )",
                         group == "y3" ~ "Group C (NO[2] )",
                         group == "y4" ~ "Group D (XO[2] )"))
long_df
#> # A tibble: 40 × 4
#>        x group value lty             
#>    <int> <chr> <int> <chr>           
#>  1     1 y1        1 Group A (CO[2] )
#>  2     1 y2        2 Group B (SO[2] )
#>  3     1 y3        3 Group C (NO[2] )
#>  4     1 y4        4 Group D (XO[2] )
#>  5     2 y1        2 Group A (CO[2] )
#>  6     2 y2        3 Group B (SO[2] )
#>  7     2 y3        4 Group C (NO[2] )
#>  8     2 y4        5 Group D (XO[2] )
#>  9     3 y1        3 Group A (CO[2] )
#> 10     3 y2        4 Group B (SO[2] )
#> # … with 30 more rows

# Plot the data
ggplot(long_df, aes(x = x, y = value, group = group, linetype = lty)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 3, color = rep(c("red", "blue"), each = 10, times = 2)) +
  scale_color_manual("Legend Title",
                     values=c("Group A (CO[2] )"="red", "Group B (SO[2] )"="blue","Group C (NO[2] )" = "red","Group D (XO[2] )" = "blue"),
                     labels=c(expression("(N"[R]*",N"[B]*")"),
                              expression("(N"[R]*",I"[B]*")"),
                              expression("(I"[R]*",N"[B]*")"),
                              expression("(I"[R]*",I"[B]*")")))+
  scale_linetype_manual("Legend Title", 
                        values=c("Group A (CO[2] )"="dashed", "Group B (SO[2] )"="dotted","Group C (NO[2] )" = "twodash","Group D (XO[2] )" = "dotdash"),
                        labels=c(expression("(N"[R]*",N"[B]*")"),
                                 expression("(N"[R]*",I"[B]*")"),
                                 expression("(I"[R]*",N"[B]*")"),
                                 expression("(I"[R]*",I"[B]*")")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution was going to be my last resort if I couldn't get it to work otherwise.

Comment: You're welcome; thanks for explaining your problem so clearly :)